# {"Cannot open database \"Namespace.Model.DbContext\" requested by the login. The login failed Login failed for user 'Domain\\myusername'."}

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I keep on getting an EntityException with an inner exception of

> {"Cannot open database \"Namespace.Model.DbContext\" requested by the
>   login. The login failed Login failed for user 'Domain\myusername'."}

I've obviously renamed the doman and user name and the namespace model and the inherited dbcontext class name.

Suspected faults 1, Connection string:

```
 <add name="Connection2" 
         connectionString="
         Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;
         Database=EmployeeDB;
         Integrated Security=True" />
```

Suspected fault 2, Code:

```
List<Employee> employees = employeeContext.Employees.ToList();
```

Comment: Your domain user hasn't got access to the database. Have you checked access permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it turned out to be the fact that I was using entity framework but did not supply the `providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"`

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to add the user in the Database users and set him as db_owner:

[image: Example of security section]

[image: Example of adding new user]

for more info please check this [Link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/08/20/sql-server-fix-error-cannot-open-database-requested-by-the-login-the-login-failed-login-failed-for-user-nt-authoritynetwork-service/)